# C++ - std::bind call operator() with perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, stdbind

I have to store arguments (parameter pack), and pass the arguments to another function.
As a result, I cannot use lambda. And a good choice is std::bind.
But for this code

```
struct A{};

void test(A &&){}

int main()
{
    A a;
    test(move(a));    //work
    bind(test,a)();   //compile fail; copy a to std::bind, pass a to test
}
```

According to standard, all variables stored in std::bind will be pass as lvalue to function. (The C++ standard doesn't say that, by I think that is what it means.)
And that means I cannot use a function (has rvalue reference in parameter) with std::bind.
One solution is to change `test(A &&)` to `test(A &)`, but this only works for your project (and make it strange while you not only need to call test by std::thread but also need to call test by plain sequential call).
So, is there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: *"I cannot use lambda"*, can you elaborate on that? and where is the parameter pack you mention ?

Comment: @NathanOliver you forgot to call `foo`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Good point.  I did that and it fails spectacularly.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, because I have to pass the arguments from this thread to another running (but suspended) thread. There is no way to store parameter pack in capture list. If I store  parameter pack inside lambda (not capture list), to make it fast, I must capture by reference, but this makes another problem.

Comment: "*There is no way to store parameter pack in capture list.*", there is, in a tuple

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I am not familiar with tuple, but I will give it a shot, thank you for your keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You can create wrapper which will be convertible to the rvalue reference (like `reference_wrapper`/l-value references) and use it with `bind`:

It cal look like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A{};

void test(A &&){ std::cout << "Works!\n"; }

template <typename T>
struct rvalue_holder
{
    T value;
    explicit rvalue_holder(T&& arg): value(arg) {}
    operator T&&()
    {
        return std::move(value);
    }
};

template <typename T>
rvalue_holder<T> rval(T && val)
{
    return rvalue_holder<T>(std::move(val));
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    test(std::move(a));    //work
    auto foo = std::bind(test, rval(std::move(a)));   //works
    foo();
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56220bc89a32c860

Note: both `rvalue_holder` and especially `rval` need further work to ensure efficiency, robustness and desired behavior in all cases.

Comment: Great. But I may not use this solution. Thanks.